# Marking a point with non integral coordinates in an image

Tags: graphics, 2d, line, point, intersection

I need to mark a point in an image.
The point's coordinates are not integral though.
I thought of drawing two intersecting segments which intersection point lies closer to the given point than the closest integral point.

An error of 1/10 pixel would be enough. The segments should be roughly 20 pixels long.

Here's an example (with shorter segments tough).

[image: example]

This is an example image I'd like to mark:

[image: The circles mark the points right now]

Comment: What is the problem You are trying to solve? I mean, isn't there other way around? I often have to mark something in an image with subpixel precision, but I save the coordinates separately and draw them when the image is shown on the screen.

Comment: @JosefBorkovec I'd like to mark where some points should lie according to a calibration. I added an image to the question. The whole thing happens in a smart camera not capable of zooming an image etc.